# Find if a path exists in a grid covered with circles of same radius

Tags: algorithm, geometry, dynamic-programming, computational-geometry

I was asked this question in an interview and I couldn't solve it.

I would be really grateful if you could help me solve it.

The problem is as follows:-

You are given a **rectangular region** whose left and **bottom-most co-ordinate** is **(0,0)** and **right-most** and **top-most** co-ordinate is **(x,y)**.

There are **n** circles with given center **co-ordinates** that exist inside the region all having the same radius **'r'**.

You are currently standing at **(0,0)** and want to reach **(x,y)** without touching any circle.

You have to tell if it is possible or not.

He told me that you can move between **2 points** freely and it is not necessary to move along the **x or y-axis**.

The solution I thought of involved taking a matrix of **x*y** dimension and for each circle, mark the points which lie inside it or touch it.

After that apply `BFS` starting from **(0,0)** to check if we can reach **(x,y)**.

He told me `BFS` will be wrong which I couldn't figure out why.

I had assumed that circles are having **integer radius** and have **integer co-ordinates**.

He also asked me to solve the question without these assumptions.

I couldn't. When asked, he told me it's a standard problem and **I should be able to find it on google**.

I couldn't, again. Please help!

Comment: BFS will take time to reach x,y as it will have to explore all the node level by level. The better option is to go for DFS approach.

Comment: approach could be like this : each co-ordinate will have a "value" field. sort the centers on the basis of x, for each co-ordinate check the distance between p(x1,y1) to Circle (cx1,cy2) is less than it's radius Cr1. if it is then mark if  co-ordinate value -1, otherise +1, (cases like (1,0) (0,1)(1,1) point (1,0) (0,1) may lie in circle but (1,1) may not. after this processing you just need to do DFS to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 2 circles can only block the path if the distance between their centers is less than 2r. So it should be enough to build "islands" of overlapping circles and check if any island blocks the path from 0 to (x,y), i.e. if any circles in it intersect rectangle borders in such a way that a straight line between those intersection points would block the path.

Comment: So what if we have 2 of these islands, one intersects the top edge of the square, and one intersects the right edge. How do you detect that there is no path available in the middle of the square area? As i understood it, the path can be a curve as well...?

Comment: if there are any 2 circles in those islands with distance <2r, the islands will be merged into a single island (that will be detected as path-blocking). otherwise they shouldn't be able to block the path.

Comment: Kind of like this: Compare each centerpoint to each other centerpoint and form islands (will be a bit of a nasty data structure). If there is any island that touches one of: 1) left and right edge, 2)left and bottom, 3) top and bottom, 4) top and right edges -> no go? :-)

Comment: yeah that's the idea

Answer (score 4):

The interviewer is wrong on the part that BFS cannot be used. Whenever you step into a cell, check that if the cell is within a circle or not, by checking the cell's distance from every other circle centers available to you, if it is within dist<=R then that cell can't be reached from the present particular cell. I solved the similar question present in interviewbit - 
https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/valid-path/
The code is simple -

```
   public class Solution {
private class Pair
{
    int x ; int y ;
}
ArrayList<Integer> xindex ; ArrayList<Integer> yindex ; int R ;int len ;
public String solve(int x, int y, int n, int r, ArrayList<Integer> xi, ArrayList<Integer> yi) {
    int dp[][] = new int[x+1][y+1] ;
    len = xi.size() ;
    for(int i=0;i<=x;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<=y;j++)
        dp[i][j] = -1 ;
    }

    xindex = xi ; yindex = yi ;
    dp[0][0] = 1 ; R = r*r ;
    LinkedList<Pair> q = new LinkedList<Pair>() ;
    Pair obj = new Pair() ;
    obj.x = 0 ; obj.y = 0 ;
    q.add(obj) ;
    int arr1[] = {1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,0} ;
    int arr2[] = {-1,0,1,1,1,0,-1,-1} ;

    while(q.size()!=0)
    {
        Pair temp = q.poll() ;
        int x1 = temp.x ;
        int x2 = temp.y ;

        for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            int t1 = x1+arr1[i] ; int t2 = x2+arr2[i] ;

            if((t1>=0)&&(t1<=x)&&(t2>=0)&&(t2<=y))
            {
                if(dp[t1][t2]==-1)
                {
                    boolean res = isValidIndex(t1,t2) ;
                    if(res==false)
                    dp[t1][t2] = 2 ;
                    else
                    {
                        dp[t1][t2] = 1 ;
                        Pair t = new Pair() ;
                        t.x = t1 ; 
                        t.y = t2 ;
                        q.add(t) ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(dp[x][y]!=-1)
        break ;
    }

    if(dp[x][y]==1)
    return "YES" ;

    return "NO" ;

}

public boolean isValidIndex(int x,int y)
{
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        int x1 = xindex.get(i) ; int x2 = yindex.get(i) ;
        if((x==x1)&&(y==x2))
        return false ;

        int n = (x1-x)*(x1-x) + (x2-y)*(x2-y) ;

        if(n<=R)
        return false ;
    }
    return true ;
}
```

}

Comment: isn't the distance from two points sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2).  In your solution, value of n would be off no?

Answer (score 2):

If two circles are touching, draw a line segment between their centers. If a circle touches an edge of the rectangle, joint its center to its projection on the closest side. Then discard the circles. This doesn't modify the connexity of the obstacles and you have turned the problem to the more famliar one of a planar straight line subdivision.

[image]

An approach could be by decomposing the domain in slabs, i.e. drawing horizontal lines through every center to partition the plane in trapezoids. Then by a seed filling approach, one can determine the starting slab and extend accessibility to the slabs that have a common horizontal side with it, until either a closed region is filled or the exit slab is reached.

Below, an intermediate step of seed filling from the top-left slab.

[image]

If the circle centers are on a regular grid, standard seed filling can do.

Answer (score 1):

***Lazy*** approach:

1. Visit each ball in turn

   - If it does not touch any other ball, scrap it.
   - If it touches another one, add it and the other one to **your favorite node graph system** and create a **connection** between them (do some housekeeping to avoid doublettes).
2. Create the extra balls A, B, C, D
3. Create extra connections (lines in the pic) between A and all balls that touch the left edge, between B and all balls that touch the top edge, etc.
4. Ask your A* if it's **willing to navigate** you from A to C / A to D / B to C / B to D.
5. If yes to any of above, then the answer to the Q is no. Quick and dirty :-).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Best approach to solve this problem is using a dfs search. First lets consider some of the basic cases like if there exist a circle containing either of the two points (i.e 0,0 or x,y) but not both then answer is "NO" and if there exist a circle containing both of the points then we can remove it from our list of circles. Now we are left with circles that don't contain either of the two points now make a graph using centers of these circles as a vertex and join any two vertex if the distance between them is less than or equal to 2*R and also maintain an array of mask for all circles, mask store the sides cut by a particular circle i.e if we number left vertical side as 0 top horizontal side as 1 right vertical side as 2 and bottom horizontal side as 3 then in mask corresponding to a particular circle those bits would be active which correspond to sides cut by that circle.
Now just perform a dfs and see whether there exist a path in graph which shows whether it is possible to move from, side 0 to 2 or side 0 to 3 or side 1 to 2 or side 1 to 2, using edges of graph (we use mask to check that). If such a path exists then answer is "NO" else answer is always "YES".

Answer (score 1):

I did this question in the exact manner as suggested by Anton. Used DSU to make so called islands. And then identified the following conditions : TB,LR,TR,LB (T: Top, B:Bottom, L:Left, R:Right ) intersections. If any of the islands made these intersections , they are sure to block the path and the answer will be "NO". 
The question can be found at Interview Bit:
https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/valid-path/
And the corresponding solution is given here:

http://ideone.com/19iSOn

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<unordered_set>
using namespace std;

class Solution{
public:
    string solve(int A, int B, int C, int D, vector<int> &E, vector<int> &F);
};

#define pii pair<int,int>

int par[1000+5];
int rnk[1000+5];
bool vis[1000+5];

void initialise(){
    for(int i=0;i<=1000;i++){
        par[i]=i;
        rnk[i]=1;
        vis[i]=false;
    }
}

int findPar(int node){
    if(par[node]==node)return node;
    return par[node]=findPar(par[node]);
}

void makeUnion(int a,int b){
    int parA=findPar(a);
    int parB=findPar(b);

    if(parA==parB)return;
    if(rnk[parA]<rnk[parB])par[parB]=parA;
    else if(rnk[parB]<rnk[parA])par[parA]=parB;
    else{
        rnk[parA]++;
        par[parB]=parA;
    }
}


bool findBlockage(int root,int X,int Y,int N,int R,vector<pair<int,pii>>vec){
    int top=0;
    int bottom=INT_MAX;
    int left=INT_MAX;
    int right=0;

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        if(par[vec[i].first]==root){
            int x=vec[i].second.first;
            int y=vec[i].second.second;
            top=max(top,y+R);
            bottom=min(bottom,y-R);
            left=min(left,x-R);
            right=max(right,x+R);
        }
    }
    if(top>=Y and bottom<=0)return true;
    if(right>=X and left<=0)return true;
    if(top>=Y and right>=X)return true;
    if(left<=0 and bottom<=0)return true;
    return false;
}

string Solution::solve(int X, int Y, int N, int R, vector<int> &E, vector<int> &F) {
    vector<pair<int,pii>> vec;
    int id=0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        vec.push_back({id,{E[i],F[i]}});
        id++;
    }

    initialise();

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(int j=i;j<N;j++){
            if(i==j)continue;
            int x1=vec[i].second.first;
            int x2=vec[j].second.first;

            int y1=vec[i].second.second;
            int y2=vec[j].second.second;

            if(((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)*(y1-y2)) <= (4*R*R)){
                makeUnion(vec[i].first,vec[j].first);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        if(!vis[par[vec[i].first]]){
            vis[par[vec[i].first]]=1;
            bool ret = findBlockage(par[vec[i].first],X,Y,N,R,vec);
            if(ret)return "NO";
        }
    }
    return "YES";
}

int main(){
    int n,x,y,r;
    cin>>x>>y>>n>>r;
    vector<int>X(n);
    vector<int>Y(n);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)cin>>X[i];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)cin>>Y[i];

    Solution sol;
    cout<<sol.solve(n,x,y,r,X,Y)<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A **recursive** solution to this problem (find path from `[0,0]` to `[x,y]` with circles as obstructions), using simple DP concepts:

```
public class Solution {
    public long radiusSquare;
    public int xDest, yDest;
    boolean vis[][];
    public final static int[] xDelta = new int[]{0, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1};
    public final static int[] yDelta = new int[]{1, 0, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1};

    public String solve(int x, int y, int radius, ArrayList<Integer> X, ArrayList<Integer> Y) {
        xDest = x; yDest = y;
        radiusSquare = radius*radius;
        int dp[][] = new int[x+1][y+1]; // = 0 (not visited), = 1 (a valid point), = 2 (invalid)
        vis = new boolean[x+1][y+1];
        if (recur(0, 0, X, Y, dp)) return "YES";
        return "NO";
    }
    public boolean recur(int xi, int yi, ArrayList<Integer> X, 
                         ArrayList<Integer> Y, int dp[][]){
        if (xi == xDest && yi == yDest) return true;
        if(vis[xi][yi]) return false; // already processed coordinate
        vis[xi][yi] = true;
        for (int i =0; i < xDelta.length; i++){
            int xArg = xi+xDelta[i];
            int yArg = yi+yDelta[i];
            if (validCoordinates(xArg, yArg, X, Y, dp) && recur(xArg, yArg, X, Y, dp)) 
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public boolean validCoordinates(int x, int y, ArrayList<Integer> X, ArrayList<Integer> Y, int dp[][]){
        if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > xDest || y > yDest) return false;

        if (dp[x][y] != 0){
            if (dp[x][y] == 1) return true; // valid coord 
            if (dp[x][y] == 2) return false;
        } 

        for (int i = 0; i < X.size(); i++){ // loop through each circle.
            long sumOfSquare = ((x-X.get(i))*(x-X.get(i))) + ((y-Y.get(i))*(y-Y.get(i)));
            if (sumOfSquare <= radiusSquare){
                dp[x][y] = 2; // comes on or inside circle
                return false;
            }
        }
        dp[x][y] = 1;
        return true;
    }
}
```